How to change the USERID of a Fuji Xerox printer using Macos Terminal?
How do I change the USERID of a Fuji Xerox printer using the Macos Terminal? Not through a graphical interface, any ideas?thanks~
Change FujiXerox printer-Printer Options-Job Accounting using the Macos Terminal
P1
P2
P3

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It can probably be done via telnet, but I have not been able to find a list of printer telnet commands. Xerox support may be able to give you such a list.
